# How can change the type of an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

the title is a little bit wrong, but I had no idea what else I could use, sry.

What I have:
I have a function k with two inputs a and b with the same type "class 'numpy.ndarray'"  and the same shape, who looks like this :

(100,)

(100,)

(100,)

(100,)

...

The coal is it to find the minimum of each vector  (shape = (100,)) of a and find the Element on b with the index of the minimum of a.

So if the first vector of a has his minimum on position [35], we want the element on position [35] but from the first vector of b.

I hope this makes sense?

In the End I would like to have integers.

Edit:

Here some example inputs

```
a = [[0.24875591 0.16306678 0.78364326 ... 0.65339055 0.36671955 0.79556977]
 [0.01090705 0.48027704 0.09681013 ... 0.19689527 0.88788462 0.64784676]
 [0.0277094  0.63714653 0.87690794 ... 0.4202944  0.52492127 0.65170223]
 ...
 [0.75916264 0.99673363 0.2800721  ... 0.7501566  0.98627157 0.06429751]
 [0.2447071  0.57766005 0.77387911 ... 0.1023757  0.71880919 0.45419627]
 [0.31396027 0.26280255 0.13444513 ... 0.51871024 0.26153987 0.63990427]]
[[0.24875591 0.16306678 0.78364326 ... 0.65339055 0.36671955 0.79556977]
 [0.01090705 0.48027704 0.09681013 ... 0.19689527 0.88788462 0.64784676]
 [0.0277094  0.63714653 0.87690794 ... 0.4202944  0.52492127 0.65170223]
 ...
 [0.75916264 0.99673363 0.2800721  ... 0.7501566  0.98627157 0.06429751]
 [0.2447071  0.57766005 0.77387911 ... 0.1023757  0.71880919 0.45419627]
 [0.31396027 0.26280255 0.13444513 ... 0.51871024 0.26153987 0.63990427]]
```

The shape of a is:

(100,)

(100,)

```
b = 
[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
```

The shape of b is:

(100,)

(100,)

The form of the output should be something like this

```
0
1
0
1
1
...
```

Comment: Could you please include a [minimal reproducible example ](/help/mcve), especially specifying inputs and expected output?

Comment: @norok2 Hello, I added some inputs in my question.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do, and it's not clear why a & b have shape (100,); (100,). Each array should have one shape.

Comment: @JonnyEnglish I'd stress the need for minimality here. Try to use a small and simple *toy* example that still reproduce the issue.

Comment: I second the comment by @BiRico, the description of the shapes of the arrays make no sense. Your title is also off whack, I will try to suggest an edit. Finally, your example of the "form of the output" is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.astype()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
return b[index].astype(int)
```

Comment: Hello,
sadly this did not work for me, the output is still somthing like this
[4]
[4]
[1]
[0]
[0]
[1]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example solution on arrays of random integers.

```py
arr_1 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=20, size=(4, 3))
arr_2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=20, size=(4, 3))

arr_1_min_inds = np.argmin(arr_1, axis=1)

arr_2_res = arr_2[np.arange(arr_1_min_inds.shape[0]), arr_1_min_inds]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `np.argmin` and use it to index into `b`:

```
b[range(len(b)), np.argmin(a, axis=1)]
```